# Is it possible to block a Keyframes Animation with steps?

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I have two divs that I want to use them like bars for statistics where each bar has `200px` of `width`.

Inside the bar I want to animate a `div`, **only one time**, increasing the width and background-color.

```
@keyframes first
{
  0%   {background-color: green; width: 0%}
  33%  {background-color: yellow; width: 33%}
  66%  {background-color: orange; width: 66%}
  100% {background-color: red; width: 100%}
}
```

I want to increase the first bar up to 150px (essentially, block the animation up to `150px` and also block the background-color animation). Is this possible with CSS or jQuery?

In this case is like to stop the animation at step **75%**

I created a JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/gefz5wtL/3/

Comment: why not adjusting the animation to 150px then? (75%)

Comment: What do you mean ? change the last step ?   In my case is important the color...bacause green must be at 0px and red at 200px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea is to run and pause the animation using JS by adding/removing classes:

```js
$('#first').addClass('first-start');
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#first').addClass('first-pause');
}, 1500);
```

```css
#page {
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#box-first,
#box-second {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

@keyframes first {
  0% {
    background-color: green;
    width: 0%
  }
  33% {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 33%
  }
  66% {
    background-color: orange;
    width: 66%
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%
  }
}

@keyframes second {
  0% {
    background-color: green;
    width: 0%
  }
  33% {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 33%
  }
  66% {
    background-color: orange;
    width: 66%
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%
  }
}

#first {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.first-start {
  animation: first 2s infinite;
}

.first-pause {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

#second {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #fff;
  animation: second 2s infinite;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page">
  <div id="box-first">
    <div id="first">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="box-second">
    <div id="second">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think is a incredible idea bt i have only one doubt...if see the update https://jsfiddle.net/rdxnvjpw/11/ i stop the animation at 1999ms when the width should be 99% and the color red... but a 1999ms the animation "start" again. I change the transition-timing-function, now is "linear"

Comment: @Borja i don't see any issue, don't forget that the code applies to only the first one

Comment: To stop the animation when the bar "is full" (so width 100% and color red) how i have to set the setInterval ? see https://jsfiddle.net/rdxnvjpw/13/

Comment: @Borja no need interval for this .. simply add `forwards` to the animation. so you only add the first class and no pause class

Comment: ahhh ok yes ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score -2):

You can use animation-fill-mode: forwards and animation-iteration-count: 1;
it will look like this:

```css
#page {
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#box-first, #box-second {
   width: 200px;
   height: 50px;
   background-color: #fff;
   border-radius: 8px;
   margin-top: 10px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

    @keyframes first
    {
      0%   {background-color: green; width: 0%}
      33%  {background-color: yellow; width: 33%}
      66%  {background-color: orange; width: 66%}
      100% {background-color: red; width: 75%}
    }
    
 
    @keyframes second
    {
      0%   {background-color: green; width: 0%}
      33%  {background-color: yellow; width: 33%}
      66%  {background-color: orange; width: 66%}
      100% {background-color: red; width: 100%}
    }   
    #first{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border-radius: 8px;
      background-color: #fff;
      animation: first 2s 1 forwards;
    }
    
    #second {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border-radius: 8px;
      background-color: #fff;
      animation: second 2s infinite;  
    }
```

```html
<div id="page">
    <div id="box-first">
       <div id="first">       
       </div>       
    </div>

    <div id="box-second">
       <div id="second">       
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```